# Legend text missing in the bubble plot (Python)

Tags: python

```
## Bubble Chart
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.scatterplot(x="PetalWidth",y="SepalWidth",data=Iris2,size="SepalLength",sizes=(20,200),palette="muted")
plt.title("Bubble Chart")
plt.legend(loc="center right",bbox_to_anchor=(1.3,0.5))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[The "SepalLength" missing in the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM8ZK.png)

[image: after the hue be added]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `size` to `hue`, or add `hue="SepalLength"`.

```
sns.scatterplot(x="PetalWidth",y="SepalWidth",hue="SepalLength", data=Iris2,size="SepalLength",sizes=(20,200),palette="muted")
```

References:

```
seaborn.scatterplot(*, x=None, y=None, hue=None, style=None, size=None, data=None, palette=None, hue_order=None, hue_norm=None, sizes=None, size_order=None, size_norm=None, markers=True, style_order=None, x_bins=None, y_bins=None, units=None, estimator=None, ci=95, n_boot=1000, alpha=None, x_jitter=None, y_jitter=None, legend='auto', ax=None, **kwargs)¶
```

[image]

Comment: It created another problem....please see the attached picture

Comment: @RaymondChang Read this page https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Comment: @RaymondChang or change size of `plot.legend( prop={'size': 3})`.

Comment: it shows "syntax error"

Comment: @RaymondChang `plt.legend( prop={'size': 3})`